# Will I still get the same rewards if I don't ask about them?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I've accepted two side quests in the game; in both cases asking about rewards was a bit too douchebaggey for me but… if there's something in it for me in addition to karma… I wouldn't *mind* it, you know what I mean?

Do I give up on rewards, or part of it, if I ask about rewards?

Comment: I'm fairly certain you get the same rewards no matter what, but I can't be bothered to test it.

Comment: @MrSmooth I don't know about that, asking about rewards before the quest can sometime lead to further duchery, i.e. trying to convince them to increase the reward.  You often don't get that option when you turn in the quest.

Answer (score 4):

I've tested two quests. One time I was a douche and asked for a reward and got it. When I repeated the quests I didn't ask for a reward, but still got them. Not sure if that was specific to those quests I did but I didn't bother repeating other quests too find out.

Answer (score 0):

Even If you don't ask about rewards in conversations before accepting missions, you still get them. I know this because I always ask as much as possible about a mission except the reward bit.